# U-Boot Automatic Redundant Booting for BeagleBoneBlack

Tags: embedded, embedded-linux, boot, u-boot

I would like to know how to properly set up redundant booting for my BBB with U-Boot. Basically, I'd like U-Boot to attempt to boot from a specific partition on my SD card and if it fails, I want it to boot from the eMMC automatically. The partition layout on my device is as follows:

```
/dev/mmcblk1p1 (eMMC boot partition)  
/dev/mmcblk1p2 (eMMC backup image)  
/dev/mmcblk0p1 (SD Card boot partition
/dev/mmcblk0p2 (SD Card image)
```

From what I understand, U-Boot will run bootcmd and I can compile U-boot with a boot count and boot limit as well as an altbootcmd. But from what I noticed, a failed boot will drop back down to the U-boot shell and I would have to manually execute to retry booting again. All I want the U-Boot to do is:
Try booting from SD. If it fails, try again and if it fails again boot from eMMC without me having to type anything in the U-Boot shell.
 How would I go about this? I am new to U-Boot but im assuming that I could write a custom bootcmd script for it?

Comment: How U-Boot will know that, if, for instance, watchdog has been fired? What I meant is that U-Boot starts (successfully!) the payload, but payload hangs.

Comment: I suggest you take a look at https://rauc.readthedocs.io/en/latest/basic.html#boot-slot-selection

Comment: Just to clarify:
Rauc is a tool to update embedded systems which is capable to do a A/B style update. Combined with, in our case, barebox + bootchooser, we can define several "slots" to boot from. The bootchooser will try to boot the desired slot. If the boot fails for whatever reason and the retry counter is 0 it boots the other slot thus basically reverting the update without changing the "old" system. The counter can be reset from userspace as well as from inside barebox itself. 

I assume you could just implement the u-boot pendant to bootchooser from barebox and use it for your usecase